# Returning the words after the first hypen is found

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list of items - `['test_item_A-engine-blade',
'test_item_A-engine-part-initial', 
'test_prop_prep-default-set']`

and I am trying to grab the words after the first hypen is found such that the result should be as follows:

- test_item_A-engine-blade => engine_blade
- test_item_A-engine-part-initial => engine_part_initial
- test_prop_prep-default-set => default_set

I tried something like `re.sub("[^A-Z\d]", "", <my string>.split('-', 1))` but it seems that it only presents me the words before the string...

Answer (score 5):

You can just use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with a maximum number of one.

```
something.split('-', maxsplit=1)
```

Comment: To keep the format of list to list, you could use a comprehension: `[i.split('-', maxsplit=1)[1] for i in myList]`, assuming that your original list is named `myList`.